# getting sizeof individual element of array pointed to by pointer -- char pointers

Tags: c, linux

I have a `char *c="hello"`  but if I do `sizeof(*c)` it will return 1 (1 byte). I like to know what is this size. Is it size of individual character of first memory address for `char *c="hello"` like `sizeof('h')` and when I do `sizeof(*(c+1))` etc still returns 1.

this is my system details

> Architecture:                    x86_64

> CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit

> Address sizes:                   36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual

> CPU(s):                          4

also In bigger project I assigned `char *c=payload_body_text`
the function is like following in the same project

```
 somefunction(struct tpacket3_hdr *ppd)
  {
    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr *) (ppd + ppd->tp_mac);
    struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) ( eth + ETH_HLEN);
    struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
    char *payload_body=(char *)(tcp + tcp->doff) ;
 }
```

So basically I like to know is `payload_body` is pointing to some area of object which is pointed to by `ppd`? which I am sure my OS has allocated before packet entered into tcp-ip stack of the kernel. tpacket3_hdr is from Packet MMAP. in a way you can call it like a packet.

Comment: Remember, `c` is still a `char *`. `char *c = "hello";` doesn't magically turn `c` from a `char *` to some new string type. `c` holds the address of the beginning of the string literal `"hello"` now, so `sizeof(*c)` will get the size of the first character in `"hello"` which is a `char`, and whose size is 1.

Comment: `sizeof("h")` will return `2`, because `"h"` is a string literal and not a character.

Comment: A `char *` does not carry information about any larger object containing the `char` to which it points.  If you need such information then either your code needs to be able to figure it out by examining the pointed-to data, or else you need to convey that information by other means.  The standard library's string functions demonstrate both approaches.

Comment: To explain @EugeneSh.'s comment: A string has a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) as the last character to signalize at what point the string is terminated.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have updated my question

Comment: What? `sizeof('h')` on that computer has value **4** and so does `sizeof(*c+1)`

Comment: I am confident that `sizeof(*c+1)` *does not* evaluate to 1.  It evaluates to the size of an `int`, which is at least 2.  For me (and probably for you) it is 4.  `sizeof(*(c+1))` would be different.

Comment: In C, a character literal in C is an `int`, not a `char`, so its size should be that of an `int`. Also in `*c + 1`, I believe the char will be promoted to an `int` when added by 1, so again, its size will be that of `int`.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang, because in C, `'h'` is an "*integer* character constant".  Its type is `int`.  C++ differs here, I believe.  On the other hand, `*c + 1` is an `int` in both C and C++, on account of the integer promotions being applied to arithmetic operands.

Comment: *So basically I like to know is payload_body is pointing to some area of object which is pointed to by ppd?* You already know it does because of the pointer arithmetic you did.  Are you saying you want to know how many valid bytes `payload_body` points to?

Comment: @dbush `Are you saying you want to know how many valid bytes payload_body points to` is there a way I can find valid bytes in payload_body like if I do `*(payload_body++)` then how do I know when to stop incrementing. since memory will always carry some garbage that can be accessed by doing `*(payload_body++)` I really like to know this

Comment: @dbush I have also corrected the question before I mistakenly asked `(*c+1)` when I had to ask `sizeof((*(c+1))`

Comment: @Alex You can't know.  At the time the data is read you should know how many bytes you have, so you need to pass that size to whatever function requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Size() operator gives you the size of whole character. It gives you the size required to assign the variable in memory. In case of 64 bit or 34 bit system, character variable reserve 1 byte address in memory.

`sizeof(*c+1)` will return 4 (in case of 64 bit; in case of 32 bit it is 2) not 1. Check it again.

Because sizeof character and integer is 1 and 4 respectively. Result of character + integer expression is a integer. So, `*c+1` will generate an integer variable and hence it will print 4 because sizeof integer variable is 4